# Is anything known about the content of Sraffa's critique of Wittgenstein's Philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein

in the preface to Wittgensteins *Philosophical Investigations* he says:

> For since beginning to occupy myself with philosophy sixteen years ago I have been forced to recognise grave mistakes in what I wrote in that first book; I was helped to realise these mistakes to a degree that I can hardly estimate by the criticism ... Of Frank Ramsey; ...[and] even more than this, by the always forcible and certain criticism ... Of Mr P Sraffa [who] for many years unceasingly practised on my thoughts.

Is there any indication on the *Investigations* itself, or in the philosophical literature, or indeed in Sraffas what the content of this critique could be? Or would it, at best, remain educated and informed  guess-work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite research that was done, and the availability of the Wittgenstein-Sraffa correspondence, there seems to be no evidence for a *specific* philosophical influence on Sraffa on Wittgenstein. The short essay ["Sraffa’s Impact on Wittgenstein"](http://wab.uib.no/agora/tools/alws/collection-7-issue-1-article-17.annotate) (Matthias Unterhuber, 2013) summarizes the currently available evidence on the subject.

The most famous story regarding Sraffa and Wittgenstein, concerning a certain *gesture* made by Sraffa, while riding on a train with Wittgenstein, was told by [Norman Malcolm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piero_Sraffa):

> Wittgenstein was insisting that a proposition and that which it describes must have the same 'logical form', the same 'logical multiplicity'. Sraffa made a gesture, familiar to Neapolitans as meaning something like disgust or contempt, of brushing the underneath of his chin with an outward sweep of the finger-tips of one hand. And he asked: 'What is the logical form of *that*?'

Sraffa's gesture is said to have made a profound impression on Wittgenstein. Still, the details of this incident, and its interpretation, are  in much dispute.

Sraffa was not a philosopher, but an economist. He didn't publish anything on philosophy, or on Wittgenstein.

The most plausible conclusion seems to me, that Sraffa influenced Wittgenstein by being for him a model of an intelligent person without philosophical training. Wittgenstein came to appreciate and to take into consideration Sraffa's raw pre-philosophical intuitions. Although there is no known direct link between Sraffa and any specific assertion or argument in Wittgenstein's texts.

Comment: It was that short story that I had in mind; but I was unsure if it wasn't an apocryphal anecdote underpinning his change in direction.

Answer (score 1):

Among Straffa's you will find two different types of texts, comments and notations. Unfortunately I could not find the quotes but here are some comments.

1. You say: circumstances. Why always torn out or made up phrases? Why
   don’t you take them from the works of some phil[osophers]
2. Cause. Is it, historically, true?
3. Remedy. Does it in fact cure?
4. Metaphysics, why not theology?
5. Psycho-An[alysis], dispute

Hope this helps